Can't get variable in .bat file to show in generated file name
I have a .bat file that generates a daily output file that we make available in a local folder location.  Recently, I was asked if I could take that file and copy it to a network location while renaming it with a datestamp (so they can keep an archive of the output file).
The file copies to the network location okay...just without the datestamp in the filename.
ECHO ON
(
    echo ---------------------- %date% %time% -------------------------------------
    SET datestr=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
    bcp DATABASE.dbo.v_SomeView out c:\temp\datafiles\SomeViewDataOut.csv -S database-server -T -c -t,
    net use Q: "\\Network\Location\To\Send\File\Copy\To"
    Q:
    COPY /b  c:\temp\datafiles\SomeViewDataOut.csv  "Q:\\SomeViewDataOut_%datestr%.csv"
    net use /delete Q: /YES
    MOVE /Y C:\Temp\DataFiles\SomeViewDataOut.csv C:\Temp\DataFiles\Processed_Files\SomeViewDataOut.csv
) >> "C:\Temp\DataFiles\LogFiles\SomeViewDataOut_Log.txt" 2>&1
EXIT

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious and this is a task I'm sure I'll be getting more requests for.  Any help would be most appreciated.
For clarity, what I'd like to see in the network location is SomeViewDataOut_20240827.csv, but what I get is SomeViewDataOut_.csv. It's just ignoring the variable part of the filename.

move set datestr=... out of your code block (see duplicate for reason or other workaround)

Thank you!  That got it.  I knew it was something simple I was missing.
